# How to execute a step depending on a condition from the previous response

Tags: karate

Hey Karate DSL Community - I was wondering if anyone could help me understand how to execute a specific test step within a scenario, based on a previous response value (Conditional logic). After reading the documentation, I have seen that this is possible with a feature files but I was also wondering how to do this elegantly within a scenario.

I will attempt to explain what I want to achieve below.

```
Given path '/games/list'
When method get
Then status 200
And def response = {"games":[{"gameId":"3431572","gameStatus":"RELEASED","releaseDate":"2018-10-31"}]}
And match response.games == '#[]'

Given path '/games/action'
And request {"game":{"gameId":"3431572","gameStatus":"RELEASED","releaseDate":"2018-10-31"},"gameAction":"DOWNLOAD"}
When method post
Then status 200
```

If `response.game.gameStatus == 'UNRELEASED'` then I would like to parse `request.gameAction = 'PREORDER'`

else if If `response.game.gameStatus == 'RELEASED'` then I would like to parse `request.gameAction = 'DOWNLOAD'`

Please let me know if you require more information. I believe the use of `set` may work here with some javascript function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds simple to me:

```
* def payload = {}
* def lookup = { UNRELEASED: 'PREORDER', RELEASED: 'DOWNLOAD' }
* payload.gameAction = lookup[response.game.gameStatus]
# ...
* request payload
```